# Не запускается Qt

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Уже и разные версии ставил и кучу форумов перерыл, так и не нашёл решения этой проблемы, ошибка вылетает сразу при запуске

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Система: Windows 7 x64)

Comment: Вы с официального сайта ставили, через лаунчер?

Comment: Не запускается Qt или Qt Creator? Судя по названию в диалоге все-таки qt creator... Сколько у вас в системе Qt стоит? В переменных путях PATH посмотрите. У меня подозрение что при запуске креатора могли dll'ки для другой версии подцепиться

Comment: Да, через лаунчер

Comment: Qt, на этой системе ещё не ставил, уже пару дней пытаюсь и безрезультатно.В PATH вообще нет Qt

Comment: `Qt Creator` ведь ставится вместе с Qt, не?

Comment: Да, вместе с Qt

Comment: А вы выше написали что Qt еще не ставили... Удалите все, что связанно с Qt, проверьте PATH причем в системных и пользовательских переменных. Поставьте Qt вместе с Qt Creator. Сейчас заходил на офф сайт и предложена была такая ссылка: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-windows-x86-online.exe

Comment: Хорошо.Возможно я в лаунчере установил что-то лишнее?

Comment: Не знаю. Слишком мало данных. Смотрите, вы говорите что проблема, но не сказали: какую версию Qt поставили, какую версию Qt Creator'a, не показали что у вас с переменными путями, не было ссылки откуда инсталятор качали, да и если в этом проблема, то хотя бы скриншотов инсталятора (чтобы как раз те самые лишние увидеть). Вот и выходит что хрен поймешь что пошло не так :)